# Google App Engine Apptrace Error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memory-profiling

I am trying to profile my GAE application using  [Apptrace](http://code.google.com/p/apptrace/wiki/UsingApptrace)
When I try to do so, I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/praveensekar/FYP/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 3245, in _HandleRequest
    self._Dispatch(dispatcher, self.rfile, outfile, env_dict)
  File "/Users/praveensekar/FYP/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 3186, in _Dispatch
    base_env_dict=env_dict)
  File "/Users/praveensekar/FYP/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 531, in Dispatch
    base_env_dict=base_env_dict)
  File "/Users/praveensekar/FYP/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2410, in Dispatch
    self._module_dict)
  File "/Users/praveensekar/FYP/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2320, in ExecuteCGI
    reset_modules = exec_script(handler_path, cgi_path, hook)
  File "/Users/praveensekar/FYP/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 2218, in ExecuteOrImportScript
    script_module.main()
  File "/Users/praveensekar/myFYP/gaecode/pknots3/pknots.py", line 289, in main
    run_wsgi_app(application)
  File "/Users/praveensekar/FYP/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/util.py", line 97, in run_wsgi_app
    run_bare_wsgi_app(add_wsgi_middleware(application))
  File "/Users/praveensekar/FYP/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/util.py", line 115, in run_bare_wsgi_app
    result = application(env, _start_response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/apptrace-0.2.1-py2.6.egg/apptrace/middleware.py", line 116, in wsgi_app
    if record: recorder.trace()
  File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/apptrace-0.2.1-py2.6.egg/apptrace/instruments.py", line 207, in trace
    obj_type = obj.__class__.__name__
AttributeError: class rnapar_2 has no attribute '__class__'
```

The error shows up if I have a class object in my code. What should I change ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was an issue with old class type. The bug is fixed in Apptrace Version 0.2.2